# Модальное окно, блокирующее только определенные окна

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня в приложении несколько окон, в каждом из котором происходят свои процессы, не связанные друг с другом. Когда я использую ShowDialog(), то окно блокирует все остальные окна.

Необходимо сделать так, что-бы модальное окно блокировало либо только родителя, либо определенный список окон. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно.

Модальное окно блокирует взаимодействие только в том потоке, в котором вызывается. Так что дели окна по потокам.

К примеру, если у тебя есть окно `A` и окно `B`, работающие в разных потоках, то при вызове модального окна в потоке окна `A`, ты заблокируешь только его. `B` продолжит работать, как не бывало.

Так же и с несколькими окнами: если у тебя в одном потоке несколько окон, то они так же разом будут блокироваться. К примеру, есть окна `A`, `B` и `C`. `B` и `C` созданы и открыты в одном потоке. Тогда вызвав модальное окно в B, ты заблокируешь сразу и `B`, и `C`, но `A` продолжит отвечать на действия.

О том, как создавать окна в новом потоке, чтобы они нормально работали уже [давно](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/) и [много](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957969/how-do-i-open-a-window-on-a-new-thread) писали. А чтобы разобраться с UI и многопоточностью нужно покопаться в [Dispatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model) - важный для таких целей класс.